# iOS Core-Graphics: Using CGContext setters to render a sharp pdf

Tags: objective-c, ios, pdf, core-graphics

I'm working on a pdf renderer using cgpdf and catiledlayer in ios and all is well except with certain fonts it's as if the vectors are to close together and I get a kind of fuzzy look like I'm not wearing glasses. The solution I'm looking into and that I'd love to get some help with is to make the grey pixels near the edge just black. I am guessing this is possible with a CGContextSet"Whatever"() method. Here is a photo to illustrate.

---

Currently rendering as...
[image: current]

---

Adobe reader app is rendering as...

[image: adobe]

and looks really sharp, so if you know the method it uses (or how to get similar) then I'll be ecstatic

---

But what I'm trying to do as a work around is turn all the grey pixels black. Something like...
[image: fine]

---

Again I am using cgcontext setter methods and noticing changes, but not all the documentation is clear on what each does, so any explanation or insight into solutions is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Adobe's renderer is aligning the bottoms of the glyphs to whole pixels, but yours is not.

These two messages on the Quartz-Dev mailing list ([one](http://lists.apple.com/archives/quartz-dev/2011/Jan/msg00004.html), [two](http://lists.apple.com/archives/quartz-dev/2011/Jan/msg00003.html)) suggest that you should try changing the settings for subpixel positioning and subpixel quantization, by using the following functions:

```
CGContextSetAllowsFontSubpixelPositioning
CGContextSetShouldSubpixelPositionFonts
CGContextSetAllowsFontSubpixelQuantization
CGContextSetShouldSubpixelQuantizeFonts
```

Either turn off subpixel positioning entirely, or turn on both subpixel positioning and subpixel quantization.  You'll have to experiment.

Post-processing Quartz's rendering is unlikely to look very good, as you've demonstrated.

Comment: Thanks I've stumbled on those methods, but nothing quite right as of yet. I'll read through those post an see if anything works. Will update with results.